# Python print first instance of a file line search

Tags: python, linux

I am parsing a .desktop file is python. I wrote the following to find the name of a app to launch.

```
 ​                ​o2​ ​=​ ​self​.​name 
 ​                ​#create a temp file so that i can... 
 ​                ​tmp​ ​=​ ​tempfile​.​NamedTemporaryFile​() 
 ​                ​with​ ​open​(​tmp​.​name​, ​'w'​) ​as​ ​f​: 
 ​                        ​f​.​write​(​o2​) 
 ​                ​#use readline for a grep like function 
 ​                ​with​ ​open​(​tmp​.​name​) ​as​ ​f​: 
 ​                        ​for​ ​line​ ​in​ ​f​.​readlines​(): 
 ​                                ​if​ ​'Name='​ ​in​ ​line​:
```

Note: self.name is a string version of the. Desktop file.. The thing is every time I do the search it finds the last item in a search, I'll use alacritty as an example.

```
 
 ​Name​=Alacritty 
 ​GenericName​=Terminal 
 ​Comment​=A fast, cross-platform, OpenGL terminal emulator 
 ​StartupWMClass​=Alacritty 
 ​Actions​=New; 
  
 ​[Desktop Action New] 
 ​Name​=New Terminal 
 ​Exec​=alacritty
```

I want it to print out the first Name= you see but it prints out the last one under [Desktop Action New] how can I fix this?

Comment: the code is not reproducible and appears truncated.

Comment: Your right I added an edit

Comment: Where are you printing it?  Are you writing a ```print``` statement on the line below the ```if``` statement? Or storing it in some variables and printing it later?

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the standard library's configparser for this?

Comment: There's a library for .desktop parsing?

Comment: Oh boy.. I just found the library and it's exactly what I needed. There goes several lines of code... Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to print the first `'Name='` but not the second one ?
If it is what you are trying to do, just break the loop after printing the first `'Name='`

```
 ​                ​o2​ ​=​ ​self​.​name 
 ​                ​#create a temp file so that i can... 
 ​                ​tmp​ ​=​ ​tempfile​.​NamedTemporaryFile​() 
 ​                ​with​ ​open​(​tmp​.​name​, ​'w'​) ​as​ ​f​: 
 ​                        ​f​.​write​(​o2​) 
 ​                ​#use readline for a grep like function 
                 last_line = None
 ​                ​with​ ​open​(​tmp​.​name​) ​as​ ​f​: 
 ​                        ​for​ ​line​ ​in​ ​f​.​readlines​(): 
 ​                                ​if​ ​'Name='​ ​in​ ​line​:
                                         print(line)
                                         #maybe do some more staff, then :
                                         break
```

That will prevent the second `'Name='` from being printed.

Comment: Lmao that's so simple I dunno how I hadn't thought of that, Noob moment. Thanks man.